# Bobby McFerrin Psalm 23

Tags: choral

Bobby McFerrin's Psalm 23 in Measures 7 & 15 does the E flat in the bass line make the tenor an E flat also?

Answer (score 3):

We could argue whether the bass Eb on beat 1 affects the tenor note on beat 4, particularly as the notation doesn't use seperate 'stems up' and 'stems down' voicing.   But I think it was sensible of the composer or editor to make it clear!    Does your version not have the Enat written?

[image]